# Pegar ultimo delimitador com explode

Tags: php

Estou querendo pegar uma extensão de um arquivo porem o nome de algumas imagens vem tipo:

> adsfasdfasd.234.asdfa.3rfr.jpg
>
> asdfsdafasdfasdf.45eg.png

Estou tentando usar o código:

```
<?php
if(is_dir("img/$noticia->idnoticia"))
{
$diretorio = "img/$noticia->idnoticia/";
if ($handle = opendir($diretorio)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
list($arquivo, $ext) = explode(strrchr($file,"."),$file);
if(($ext!="mp3")AND($ext!="wav")){
echo "<li><img src='$diretorio$arquivo.$ext'></li>";
```

Porem o resultado esta sendo `.`.

alguma dica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) com a opção `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` para obter *exclusivamente* essa informação.

```
$string = "adsfasdfasd.234.asdfa.3rfr.jpg";
echo pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // jpg
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://ideone.com/t54rOc)</kbd>

O seu código deveria ficar semelhante a isto:

```php
$diretório = getcwd(); // Diretório atual

if ($handle = opendir($diretório)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (is_file($file) && $file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $info = pathinfo($file);
            $arquivo = $info['filename']; // Nome do arquivo
            $ext = $info['extension'];    // Extensão
        }
    }
    closedir($handle); // Fecha o manipulador aberto por opendir()
}
```

Comment: editei a pergunta com as alteracoes que sugeriu porem agora so retorna = .

Comment: @ArsomNolasco Será que você não está passando o nome de um arquivo ao invés do diretório na variável `diretorio`? dê uma olhada nesse [comentário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php#116742) do site do PHP.

Comment: o problema e que preciso tambem alem de listar tudo pegar o nome do arquivo separado postei o codigo completo

Comment: @ArsomNolasco Digitei errado a mensagem anterior.. o problema inicial ainda persiste? dê uma olhada no código atual da resposta.

Comment: sim sim deu certo, de alguma maneira eu achei que usar o LIST era obrigatorio, porem me parece que a funcao pathinfo ja lista, obr

Answer (score 3):

Complementando o que já foi respondido anteriormente, seguem algumas alternativas ao `pathinfo`, apenas para mostrar outros meios de se trabalhar com *strings*, dada a  alta performance no caso de operações simples deste tipo.

### Obtendo só a extensão:

Não usei `list` combinado com `explode` por não funcionar corretamente no caso de vários pontos no meio do nome.

Usando explode:

```
$ext = end( explode( '.', $file) );
```

Usando operações string (preferível):

```
$ext = strrchr( $file, '.' ); // retorna do último ponto em diante .jpg
```

também:

```
$ext = substr( strrchr( $file, '.' ), 1); // retorna jpg (sem o ponto)
```

ou mesmo:

```
$pos = strrpos( $file, '.' );
$ext = ( $pos === false ) ? '' : substr( $file, $pos + 1 );
```

### Obtendo extensão e o nome do arquivo:

```
$pos = strrpos( $file, '.' );
$ext = ( $pos === false ) ? '' : substr( $file, $pos + 1 );
$arq = ( $pos === false ) ? $file : substr( $file, 0, $pos );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/cV02uN)**.

Comment: mais como fazer listando ? list($file) = end( explode( '.', $file) );  << nao funciona

Comment: o problema de listar é que você nao pegaria o nome inteiro de um arquivo se viesse com dois pontos, por isso nao pus exemplo com list. Teria que usar reverse no array, algo desse tipo: `list( $ext, $arquivo ) = array_reverse( explode( '.', $file ) )`. Notar que inverti a posição do ext, e como disse, se tiver `um.arquivo.jpg` o "um" vai ficar de fora. Explode e list não são adequados para isto.